# How to programmatically change the z-order of VideoViews in Android

Tags: android, android-videoview, z-order

I have an android app with a RelativeLayout, to which I programmatically add multiple VideoViews, all of which are playing at the same time. The VideoViews can be moved around by dragging, and they can be moved so that they overlap.

The problem is that I cannot find a way to change the z-order of them during the runtime. .bringToFront() brings the view to front for receiving touch events, however the order of the actual videos remains the same.

I have tried removing and re-adding the videoView by .removeChild(), however that stops and resets the video.

Is there a way to change the z-order of the videos? A "hacky" way would work too, e.g. removing ad re-adding the view without stopping and resetting the video.

Thanks

P.S. It's a streaming video, so restarting the video to the same position would not work, there would be way too big delay.

EDIT: Even though people suggest multiple VideoViews should not work, they do work great, even overlapping, at least on my Nexus S, ICS 4.0.3

EDIT 2: Actually, not great, the second video sometimes flickers, but that's fine for this purpose. The 3rd and 4th video don't flicker, which is a bit weird

Comment: Last I checked, multiple `VideoViews` did not work at all. You may wish to spend some time testing this on various hardware to ensure your approach will be reliable before investing much more time in it, if you have not done so already.

Comment: In Android, if something works great on one device, it really doesn't mean anything in terms of whether that is supported or not. If you're not going by documented information (and even then, that's always definitely not bullet proof) I would test on 15 devices before I thought something might work. It's just Android.

Answer (score 1):

The [document](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html#setZOrderMediaOverlay%28boolean%29) says the Z-order of SurfaceView's are determined before they are attached to window, and their orders are not altered once attached. Since VideoView's are also SurfaceView, I don't think it is possible to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The VideoViews use SurfaceView, witch is Z-ordered with the windows, but you cannot have multiple SurfaceView  z-ordered,because every SurfaceView will punches a hole on the window. If you add multiple video on the same area, video will not play correctly. I used to translate video out off the screen to keep its state. Look for EcoNews aap on google play.